Using IntersectionObserver to detect scrolling below a target - and keeping it until next target comes into view
Using IntersectionObserver - is it possible to detect scroll intersecting AND past/below every entry - until the next entry comes is scrolled into view (other elements are between the entries.)?
In the example below, I would like to detect scrolling below every element with the class .title, and keep it until the next element with the class .title appears.
I tried with the below, but it doesnt't work as expected.
Hope my questions makes sense. :)


let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '-50px 0px -50px 0px',
    threshold: [.5]
}

let sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, options) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting && window.scrollY >= entry.boundingClientRect.top) {
            // Do something here when scrolling below this entry - until next entry is in view.
            console.log(entry.target);
        }
    });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach((section) => {
    sectionObserver.observe(section);
});
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Title one</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
    ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
    ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
    mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
    Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
    tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
    lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
    aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
    tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
    felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
    pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title">Title two</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
    ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
    ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
    mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
    Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
    tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
    lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
    aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
    tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
    felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
    pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title">Title three</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
    ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
    ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
    mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
    Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
    tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
    lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
    aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
    tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
    felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
    pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title">Title four</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
    ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
    ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
    mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
    Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
    tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
    lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
    aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
    tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
    felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
    pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title">Title five</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor.`enter code here`
    Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros.
    Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices,
    consectetur

    mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
    Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
    tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
    lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
    aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
    tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
    felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
    pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tem

    pus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
</div>




Is this what your asking.


const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title')

onscroll = () => {
     const SP = window.scrollY
     let x = 0

     titles.forEach((title, i)=>{

          if(SP>titles[i].offsetTop && SP<titles[i+1].offsetTop) {
               console.log(`title ${(1+i)} is not showing on the screen`)
               x = 1+i
          }

          if((SP+screen.height)>titles[i].offsetTop && 1+i != x) {
               console.log(`title ${(1+i)} is now showing`)
          }

     })
          
};
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="container">
          <div class="title">Title one</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title two</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title three</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title four</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title five</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor.`enter code here`
            Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros.
            Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices,
            consectetur
        
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tem
        
            pus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>

          <div class="title">Title 6</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title 7</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title 8</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title 9</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut
            ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean
            ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
          <div class="title">Title 10</div>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor.`enter code here`
            Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros.
            Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices,
            consectetur
        
            mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh.
            Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non
            tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
            lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.
        
            Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit
            aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
            tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum
            felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget
            pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tem
        
            pus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
          </p>
     </div>
     
     <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




yes, I can work with that. Thank you.

Intersection Observer API performs better than Scroll Listener. Please check this article for performance comparison.
What you did in your code is logically correct. You just need to correct the implementation's syntax. Best way to learn something new is to look at the official documentation.


const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

const observerHandler = function (entries, observer) {
   entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
         console.log(`Intersects viewport`);
         // Do something when it intersects
         observer.unobserve(entry.target); // Stops observing the target element to prevent the callback from being triggered on future intersections, useful when you only need to handle the event once.
      }
   });
};
      
const options = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.5,
      };
      
const sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
        observerHandler,
        options
      );
      
sections.forEach((section) => sectionObserver.observe(section));
<div class="container">
      <section>
        <div class="title">Title one</div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus
          dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel
          rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula
          eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut
          ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in,
          consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida,
          pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum.
          Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius
          non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec
          dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis.
          Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet
          elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien
          sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare
          dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus
          justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius.
          Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus
          enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis
          auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim
          pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="title">Title two</div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus
          dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel
          rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula
          eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut
          ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in,
          consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida,
          pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum.
          Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius
          non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec
          dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis.
          Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet
          elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien
          sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare
          dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus
          justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius.
          Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus
          enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis
          auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim
          pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="title">Title three</div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus
          dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel
          rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula
          eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut
          ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in,
          consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida,
          pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum.
          Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius
          non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec
          dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis.
          Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet
          elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien
          sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare
          dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus
          justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius.
          Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus
          enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis
          auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim
          pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="title">Title four</div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus
          dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel
          rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula
          eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut
          ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in,
          consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida,
          pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum.
          Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius
          non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec
          dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis.
          Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet
          elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien
          sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare
          dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus
          justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius.
          Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus
          enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis
          auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim
          pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="title">Title five</div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus
          dolor id ullamcorper tempor.`enter code here` Donec ut ullamcorper
          tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at,
          imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla.
          Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices,
          consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam
          nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu
          tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin
          elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula
          vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque
          lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit
          amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a
          sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra,
          ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet
          tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac
          varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id.
          Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros.
          Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque
          dignissim pellentesque et tem pus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>



